# How to join 2 tables with a common column in another 3rd table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I want to join table **people** with table **video** but they don't have direct common column between them but both tables have common column with table **village** so help me out to join table **people** with table **video**.

#### PEOPLE

```
id                 village_id
 1                 smg
```

#### VIDEO

```
id               village_id
 1                 smg
```

#### VILLAGE

```
id               name
smg                hdd
```

I have tried the following code but its not working:

```
SELECT people.id, video.id
FROM people
JOIN village ON people.village_id = village.id
JOIN video ON video.village_id = village.id
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Your query looks fine to me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e797b4/1

Answer (score 0):

If the table structure you provided is correct, then you do have a link between videos and people. You have village_id...

```
SELECT p.id , vid.id 
FROM people  as p 
INNER JOIN video as vid 
    ON vid.village_id = p.village_id
```

IF you don't want any repeated values, then you could do a `SELECT DISTINCT` like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id , vid.id 
FROM people  as p 
INNER JOIN video as vid 
    ON vid.village_id = p.village_id
```

Could you provide more details on what exactly you are wanting?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  * FROM

(SELECT people.village_id AS pv_id, village.id AS v_id FROM
people JOIN village ON people.village_id = village.id) AS T

JOIN video ON video.village_id = T.v_id;
```

I am assuming you want to do a triple JOIN. I first joined people and village into a table and named it as T and joined T with video table.